# Interview for a mathematical periodical

Tags: mathematics, journals

I ("interviewer") am a mathematician and plan to publish an interview with another (very famous, much more senior) mathematician ("interviewee") in a periodical of a local mathematical organization.

I already recorded a rather informal interview/conversation (a few years back, actually) and we are now turning this into an interview-style text.

Two questions:

1. This text certainly does not adhere to any journalistic standards (which I am sure to exist) required of an interview. We now freely change order and contents of questions and answers to make the text clearer and hopefully more interesting; the interviewee can of course object to include anything of what was said and even add stuff that they forgot to mention in the original conversation etc. I do not desire to meet any journalistic standard but would like to avoid giving a wrong impression by calling the text "interview". Is there a standard disclaimer for such a conversation? Is it enough to just mention "this text is based on a conversation recorded in ... and edited in ..."? (I want to call it "interview" and not "conversation" or whatever.)
2. Who is the "author" of such a thing? The interviewer (who asks the question and types and edits it)? This seems to be the case in a "proper newspaper interview" (which this text is not). Or the interviewee (who provides the relevant part, the answers?) Or is it a joint work?

Comment: Have you looked at the several dozen interviews that have been published in College Mathematics Journal? See [search1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Interviewed+by+G.+L.+Alexanderson%22) and [seach2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Interviewed+by+Donald+J+Albers%22) for some of these. These interviews have been collected together into (at least) two books (in fact, I have the two books in front of me right now as I'm preparing this comment), but for your purposes it would probably be better to look at the actual journal papers to see how what your asking was done.

Comment: [This JSTOR search](https://www.jstor.org/action/doAdvancedSearch?q0=MP&jc.TheCollegeMathematicsJournal=j100753) brings up many of the interviews I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Great, thanks! It seems that for 2, it is possible to list as author (metadata) both {Interviewer, Interviewee}, and use as title/author combination in the actual document "An interview with Interviewee\\by Interviewer". This seems very reasonable.

Comment: Jakob, (hi!) it seems to me many mathematical interviews follow the format you suggest. Equations, technical explanations, etc, are added when the original exchange is transcribed and edited. This is also the case for interviews in literary magazines, where the interviewee receives the text for editing and further comments, sometimes through several rounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Although the question has answers in the comments, I'm providing an answer so that this question does not remain unanswered.)

Articles that are based on interviews with mathematicians published in periodicals of mathematical societies typically have the title "Interview with [interviewee]" and have the interviewer as the author (that is, the interviewee is not an author).

As an example, see Jackson, A. & Kotschick, D. (1998). "[Interview with Shiing Shen Chern](https://www.ams.org/notices/199807/chern.pdf)," *Notices of the AMS*, 45(7), 860-865.

The article starts with the note: "This article is based on an interview with Shiing Shen Chern conducted on March 4, 1998, by Allyn Jackson, with mathematical help from Dieter Kotschick."  Also note that aside from Jackson, Kotschick is also listed as an author of the article.  (See [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/199807/index.html).)